# How are we able to create more than one object of same name if object created in Java are stored in heap

Tags: java, multithreading

(http://tutorials.jenkov.com/images/java-concurrency/java-memory-model-2.png)(I cannot paste diagram here. But link is given)

At specifically this link http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html it is said that, objects created are stored in Heap nevertheless of which thread created it. Now I wanted to ask if I create same object in run() method and say create 10 threads and start them, my question is, how are objects with same name getting created?

```
    public void run(){
        String t = new String();
        Integer n = new Integer(5);
    }
```

Comment: Object don't have names, you can't associate a name with an object without adding a field like `String name` in the object.  Your `t` and `n` are references and you can only have one variable with that name in the current scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are correct as far as they go, but I think they leave out the most important point that is confusing you.

`t` and `n` are not objects.  They are *variables*.

Variables have names.  Objects don't.  Objects in Java can only be accessed indirectly.  A named Java variable holds a *reference* to a nameless object that lives somewhere in the heap.

Variables can exist in any of several places:

*instance* variables live inside objects.

*class* variables (a.k.a., `static` variables) live inside `Class` objects.

*local* variables, and function *argument* variables live in a data structure called an *activation record* that lives in a *call stack*.

Call stacks and activation records are not Java objects, and there is no means to explicitly access them.  Each thread has its own call stack which is inaccessible to any other thread.

So, if you have ten *activations* of your `run()` function in ten different threads, each activation has its own separate `t` and `n` local variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is called variable *scope*. Each reference name has its scope and can not be visible outside it. In your example reference `String t` and `Integer n` are defined in the method body. This scope is called *local*. You can refer to objects under these references only inside method `run` body. And each thread will have it's own run method (code will be the same but objects will be different) and because you can't get this references outside of `run` the can not interfere.

Answer (score 0):

At running time, each time a process creates an object, Java gives them a different reference (you can check this while in debugging mode).

The variable in your code, gives a name to this reference so you are able to manipulate the object but only inside its *scope* (roughly between braces).

Any new execution of run will create a new object which could only by referenced by your local (inside its scope) variables, so you will have to devise a way to access those objects, maybe saving your references to some sort of list at class level (class scope).